# IE and multiple float elements

Tags: css, css-float

i'm trying to position a number of buttons with float and it works just fine in all browsers. but the Internet Explorer adds some wird element after the 2 floating button (or before the third floating button).
Can anybody help me?
[Here's a picture!](http://sandbox.lddesign.de/menu.jpg)

Here's my code:

```
<style type="text/css">

            .button {
                width:auto;
                height:23px;
                border:1px solid #cccccc;
                border-radius:4px;
                background-image:url('bg_button.jpg');
                background-position:left;
                background-repeat:repeat-x;
                font-family:Tahoma;
                font-size:13px;
                float:left;
                margin-right:4px;
                cursor: pointer;
                padding-right:10px;
            }
...........
</script>


<div class="button">
        <a href=''>
        <div>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <a href=''>
        <div>
            Button 1 aksjd fklaj sdklfaj sdlkfasdf  
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <a href=''>
        <div>
            Button 1    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Which IE? Which rendering mode (Standards or Quirks)? Are you in compatibility mode? What does the DOM inspector reveal? Can you show us a live example?

Comment: IE 9. But i remember having something like this in IE 8 too.
i'd say it's in standard mode.
<!doctype html>

Comment: http://sandbox.lddesign.de/border.php

Answer (score 0):

Put a full-width container around everything and float that.

I can't say for sure it will work (since I can't reproduce it), but in IE floating the parent very frequently helps.

Edit: Never mind.

You can't put a `div` inside an `A`. If you do, the browser will close the `A` before the div and then you have all sorts of weird problems. (And you aren't even closing 2 of your `A`'s.)

Use `span` instead, and if you need to, put `style="display: block;"` on the `span`.

Comment: oh, i didn't close the a tags :-(
sorry for that....
but i guess you're right about divs inside an a, anyway